# Confusing Simile For Me

Tags: phrase-usage

> The engines roared and pilots jumped and leaned forward. And **like a helicopter takes off**, so too did the pilots as they sped around obstacles, flying close to the water.

I came across this paragraph in an article I was reading and felt that the usage of *like a helicopter takes off* seemed off. I know there's a large possibility of it being grammatically correct, I just can't wrap my head around it since I've never seen this structure before. *And like how a helicopter takes off* would've been much easier for me to understand. Can I ask for assistance in understanding this?

Comment: Please ***Link to the source***   It is pretty obvious when you find out they are talking about **people with jet packs**  ! https://engoo.com/app/daily-news/article/iron-man-pilots-take-off-in-dubai-jet-suit-race/s6v1VtlOEe603nvFUfqEMQ

Comment: "Like how" doesn't work. The conjunction *like* means *in the same way* (*in the same manner*).

Comment: Do you know a language where the equivalent of *like how* would be perfectly fine? (I ask just to understand why you find *like how a helicopter takes off* easier to understand.) I speak Italian, but in Italian *like how* would result on the same word repeated twice. We say the equivalent of *like an helicopter takes off*.

Comment: "In an article...“ this needs CONTEXT! After six hours the post has no link to the original source. -1 I will happily reverse the downvote when the source is added.

Answer (score 2):

Helicopters take off vertically (unlike aeroplanes, which take off horizontally)

These people wearing jet packs take off vertically, like a helicopter.

Comment: I was about to vote to close when I realized that the sentence quoted in the question is referring to the helicopter's ability to take manuever *laterally* as it ascends, and can stop ascending.